70s YA adventure 4 boys to moon in Apollo-style rocket/capsule
Summary -  4 boys go to moon in standard space rocket - one has helmet confiscated for snitching chocolate
In discussing childhood books today, I remembered one series that were similar in tone to Willard Price's Adventure series.  Those were not sci-fi but the one I remember was, and I think the others in the series might have been.  I read these at about the same time, so early 70s in England, although of course the books could be earlier.
There were 4 boys, I believe the three eldest were brothers and then a fourth lad who had a slightly problematic past.  They were chosen to man a standard rocket to the moon with a landing capsule, very much like the real moon landings.  To give him a sense of responsibility, the fourth lad was put in charge of the supplies.
At one point the eldest confronts the lad because he has been sneaking chocolate bars from the supplies.  The lad's viewpoint is that he is just taking "his" quarter-share, but the eldest points out how they are supposed to be shared, and how would he feel when the other 3 were eating their bars and he had none left.  The eldest takes the lad's space helmet with him on an expedition, so the lad is trapped & can "think about his position".  The lad defiantly eats another bar of chocolate.
The expedition gets into trouble, the lad comes up with a possible solution but when ground control says he should go out to fix it he has to sheepishly admit the eldest has his helmet.  I think the eldest just came back with it & they go out together to fix everything, resulting in a happy ending for all.
In later books, I think the lad was treated as an adopted brother.

Tom Swift? That always seemed to me to be the sci-fi version of Willard Price

"Moon Base One" from the "Chris Godfrey of Unexa" series by Hugh Walters? The boy is called Tony Hale. http://unexa.org/walters/04moonba/index.html

That's it - funny how I didn't remember anything about the pandemic, only the chocolate!
